# Java Hibernate AutoIncrement Identity set ID to start 0 mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, auto-increment, identity

i have a simple class like this

```
public class IdClass
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4594459221202802623L;
    private Integer id;
    public IdClass(){}
    public IdClass(Integer id){super();this.id = id;}   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId(){return this.id;}
    public void setId(Integer id){this.id = id;}        
}
```

which have `autoIncrement in MYSQL table` everything was working smoothly but we need to delete all records in the table to start once again later i save the new first record into de table but the sequence use the last ID generate (+1) before the delete i was wondering if it is possible to set the ID to start from 0 or 1 again...thanks a lot..

Comment: You might have to drop the entire table to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in three ways

1. Directly Reset Autoincrement Value

   `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1;`
2. Truncate Table

   `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;`

   This will reset the auto increment on the table as well as deleting all records from that table.
3. Drop and Recreate

   `Table DROP TABLE table_name;`

   `CREATE TABLE table_name { ... };`

Source:

[How To Reset MySQL Autoincrement Column](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/reseting-mysql-autoincrement-column/)

Comment: i just delete all records previosly so this worked ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; thanks a lot.